# Absolute value of $\sin z$ on square

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Show that $|\sin z|\geq 1$ at all points on the square with vertices $\pm (N+1/2)\pi\pm(N+1/2)\pi i$, for any positive integer $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|\sinh(y)| = |e^{y} - e^{-y}|/2 >1$ if $|y| >  \ln(1 + \sqrt{2})$.